# Address length of a string literal

Tags: c, gcc, memory, constants, string-literals

I see that on Linux systems with GCC the address of string literals seems to be much smaller than for other variables. For instance the following code generates the o/p shown below it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *str1 = "Mesg 1";
    char *str2 = "Mesg 2";
    char str3[] = "Mesg 3";
    char str4[] = "Mesg 4";

    printf("str1 = %p\n", (void *) str1);
    printf("str2 = %p\n", (void *) str2);
    printf("&str3 = %p\n", (void *) str3);
    printf("&str4 = %p\n", (void *) str4);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
str1 = 0x400668
str2 = 0x40066f
&str3 = 0x7fffcc990b10
&str4 = 0x7fffcc990b00
```

Is there a constant address space separate for such usage?

Comment: Most likely string literals are just in the text segment, which typically lives at a relatively low address. Why does it matter to you ?

Comment: I was just curious to know the reason given the strange difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard does not specify where string literals will reside but most likely it would be in the read only data section. For example on a Unix system using `objdump` you can inspect the read only data section like this:

```
objdump -s -j .rodata a.out
```

and using a [Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/494ca248fcfc1286) we can see output similar to this:

```
Contents of section .rodata:
 400758 01000200 4d657367 20310073 74723120  ....Mesg 1.str1 
 400768 3d202570 0a004d65 73672032 00737472  = %p..Mesg 2.str
 400778 32203d20 25700a00 26737472 33203d20  2 = %p..&str3 = 
 400788 25700a00 26737472 34203d20 25700a00  %p..&str4 = %p..
```

The C99 draft standard section `6.4.5` *String literals paragraph 5* says:

> [...] The multibyte character sequence is then used to initialize an array of **static storage duration** and length just sufficient to contain the sequence.[...]

which means the lifetime of the string literal is the lifetime of the program and *paragraph 6* says:

> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the
>   appropriate values. If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
>   undefined.

So we don't know if they are distinct, that is going to be an implementation choice but we do know that we can not modify them. Otherwise it does not specify how they should be stored.

Comment: Thanks Shafik Yaghmour. I was just looking for some answer from the Bible (specification) :)

Answer (score 3):

```
char *str1 = "Mesg 1";
char *str2 = "Mesg 2";
char str3[] = "Mesg 3";
char str4[] = "Mesg 4";
```

`str1` and `str2` are pointer objects, pointing to string literals -- or, more precisely, to the anonymous static array objects associated with those string literals. Those arrays have *static storage duration*, which means that they exist for the entire execution of the program. They're also read-only, which can affect where the implementation chooses to store them. (BTW, since string literals are read-only, the pointers to them should be declared as `const`.)

`str3` and `str4` are not pointers; they're array objects initialized with the specified values. They have *automatic storage duration*, which means that they exist only during the execution of the nearest enclosing block (in this case, while the `main` function is executing). For `main`, there's not much practical difference unless you play tricks with recursive calls or `atexit` handlers, but for other functions it matters. Objects with automatic storage duration are typically allocated on the stack, and deallocated when the function returns.

(An array expression, in most contexts, is implicitly converted to a pointer to the array's first element. See section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/) for details.)

On your system, apparently read-only static objects are allocated at low addresses around `0x400000`, and the stack is at much higher addresses just below `0x800000000000` (2<sup>47</sup>). This can vary from one system to another.

It's important to note that all these addresses have the same length. You seem to be using a 64-bit system. `0x400668` is not a 32-bit address; it's a 64-bit address that happens to have a small numeric value. The output format used by `printf` for `%p` is implementation-defined; it *could* have printed:

```
str1 = 0x0000000000400668
str2 = 0x000000000040066f
&str3 = 0x00007fffcc990b10
&str4 = 0x00007fffcc990b00
```

Comment: Yes, I am indeed using a 64-bit system. I tried the following variant:

    `printf("str1  = %014p\n", (void *) str1);`

    `printf("str2  = %014p\n", (void *) str2);`
    `printf("&str3 = %014p\n", (void *) str3);`
    `printf("&str4 = %014p\n", (void *) str4);`

And it prints:

    `str1  = 0x000000400668`
    `str2  = 0x00000040066f`
    `&str3 = 0x7fffc17a57c0`
    `&str4 = 0x7fffc17a57b0`

Is that proper way to test?

Comment: @user926918: Not really. I'm not sure `%014p` is even well defined, and even if it is, it's just going to add some meaningless zeros to the output. To get the size of a pointer, use `sizeof`. That's a little tricky with arrays; I'll update later with details. Just what are you trying to test?

Comment: I am trying to verify what you said (no offence, just curious). :)

Comment: More details: `sizeof str1` will give you the size of a `char*` pointer (should be 8 on your system). `sizeof str3` will give you the size of the array, which is 7 (6 for the characters of the string plus 1 for the terminating `'\0'`) -- because `sizeof` is one of the contexts in which the usual array-to-pointer conversion ("decay") doesn't happen. You can use `sizeof &str3[0]` to get the size of the pointer to the array's first element, which again will be 8 on your system. Some pointer values just happen to have a lot of leading zeros; that's not something you should normally care about.

Comment: But if you're trying to track down where a particular pointer value came from, knowing how your compiler allocates memory can be useful. Note that, as far as the C language is concerned, pointers are not integers. But printing a pointer value with `%p` *typically* gives you a human-readable representation of the internal representation of the pointer value, which typically *looks like* an N-bit integer.

Comment: @user926918: No offense taken, of course. (And see my previous two comments; I'm not sure whether you would have received a notification).

Comment: The actual reason for my curiosity comes from the fact that OpenCL implements const memory separately and was wondering if it is being implemented here too by the OS. That was the reason I did not use the sizeof on the ptr, as it will be able to point to arrays as well. I tried printing the leading zeros as the specification did not say it is not required for pointers! And thanks a lot for the time taken to answer in so much detail.

Answer (score 2):

> **Is there a constant address space separate for such usage?**

No, this is completely implementation dependent. Only things assured are:

- A string literal remains alive throughout the lifetime of your program and
- You get a undefined behavior if you modify a string literal in anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Some implementations put string literals in a read-only data segment, which will likely have significantly different addresses from regular data. This varies by implementation,  though, so don't assume it's universal.